# Проблема с точность float при вычислениях

Tags: c#, float, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, точность

Вот простой пример.

`float number = 0.9f;`

`number -= 0.1f;`

`// ВЫВОД: number = 0,79999995`

Мне нужно получить 0,8. Как решить проблему с точностью?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте вместо `float decimal`

```
decimal number = 0.9m;
number -= 0.1m;
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Comment: По заданию нужно использовать float

Comment: Как звучит задание?

Comment: Так выводится значение 0,8 при типе данных float

Comment: У меня нет. Работаю на c# .net core

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку `0.79999995` - это реальное значение переменной типа `float` в данном случае (ну, не умеет этот тип хранить числа с абсолютной точностью), то у вас один вариант - ограничить точность отображения переменной при выводе, тогда она округлится до нужного вам значения:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        float number = 0.9f;
        number -= 0.1f;
        Console.WriteLine($"{number:f1}");
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
0.8
```

[Ссылка](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mgWhwS) на код на `dotnetfiddle` в среде `.NET 5`

Comment: А если мне надо далее работать с переменной?

Comment: @mrabets Работайте, кто ж вам мешает. Но учтите, что точного значения переменная `float` хранить не умеет, всегда будет приблизительное. Но обычно и такого хватает для обычных вычислений.